# Can't understand NullPointerException

Tags: listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I'm experimenting with ListViews and ArrayAdapters, and i've come into a runTimeException issue, the DDMS error report is telling me that i'm having a NullPointerException at the line containing "public void onItemClick", I cant see why it is giving me a issue.

```
 package com.example.worksheet2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ListView listview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] values = { "A", "B", "C" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.id.menu_settings, values);

    // asign adapter to listview
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
    });

}

   }
```

Here's the error report

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.worksheet2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
```

Comment: OK so which line is `MainActivity.java:31`?

Comment: Like I said the line containing _listview.setOnItemClickListener(){}_

Comment: Post the **full** stack trace.

Comment: No, you said "onItemClick".

Comment: Every time I test it jumps around between that area

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the listview an id, and then find it by id.